# jQuery - If Select Not Selected Being Ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code, and as you can see, I am choosing to execute the actions only when the select field of the 7th td element is not selected. Even so, the code is being executed when the value is selected on page load.

Is there something else I must do to ensure this works properly?

```
if (jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(7) select").is(':visible') && jQuery('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(5) select option:selected').length > 0 && jQuery('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(7) select option:not(:selected)')) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select option").each(function() { this.selected = (this.text == "<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); ?>"); });
    jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select option").change();
    $('finder-4023--20454').simulate('click'); // This is the ID of the select element ( it is the same as div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select )
    $('finder-4023--20454').simulate('change'); // This is the ID of the select element ( it is the same as div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select )
    console.log('Changed!');
  }, 700);
  jQuery("#popover6").show();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you need an event handler, as right now it only runs on pageload

Comment: how many rows are there? and you need to move the `if` condition inside the timeout handler may be

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net... too many unknowns without seeing live version

Comment: If this is an ID, selector is wrong: `$('finder-4023--20454')` should be `$('#finder-4023--20454')`